# Setting up different environments with single Bullhorn account

Tags: rest, api, server, jobs

I am using **Bullhorn Rest API**. And I have two servers, i) **Development Server** -> Here test users entries are created for testing and checking progress will be done via Bullhorn Rest API. ii) **Production Server** -> In this server real site users will be created and working with the site via Bullhorn Rest API. So I need to set the two different states (of data or entries for candidate, job) in Bullhorn. How can we achieve this?